# Java Level order to N-Ary tree (Iterative and not recursion)

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, preorder

trying to convert a level order input to a N-Ary tree. Where levels are separated by a null. Example.
Input: [1, null, 2,3,4, null,5,6,null,7,8,null,9,10]
Code is expected to build a tree and finally print the preorder of the same for validation.

Output: [1,2,5,6, 3,7,8,4,9,10]

Not getting the desired output. Also this needs to be solved iteratively and recursion may not be used. Below is the full code. Added some print statement to ease debugging.

```
enter code here

package AllTree;

import java.util.*;

public class ListToNArrayTree {
    public static class Node{
        public int val;

        public ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();

        public Node (int val){
            this.val = val;
        }

        public Node (int val, ArrayList<Node> children){
            this.val = val;
            this.children = children;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return " " + val;
        }

        public ArrayList<Node> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

        public void setChildren(ArrayList<Node> children) {
            this.children = children;
        }

    }


    public static Node buildTree(List<Integer> dataAsList){

        /*Check if the input is valid to create a tree example {1, null, 2,3,4, null,5,6,null,7,8,null,9,10, null};
        Above is a level order so null is mandatory @ position 1.
         */
        if (dataAsList.isEmpty() || dataAsList.get(0) == null|| dataAsList.get(1) !=null){
            System.out.println ("Invalid data to construct a tree");
            return null;
        }

        /*Create queue to hold all values from input*/
        Queue<Integer> dataAsQueue = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Integer data: dataAsList) {
            dataAsQueue.add(data);
        }

        /*Create queue to hold the nodes which will be retrieved in FIFO to add corresponding children*/
        Queue<Node> dataAsTree = new LinkedList<>();


        Node root = new Node(dataAsQueue.poll()); // to poll the root element
        dataAsQueue.poll(); // to poll the null  - as after this is the beginning of the second level of the tree
        dataAsTree.add(root);

         root =  dataAsTree.poll();
         Node parent = root;

        while (!dataAsQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Node parent_ = parent;
            Integer childInt= dataAsQueue.poll();
            if (childInt != null){
                parent_.getChildren().add(new Node(childInt));
                dataAsTree.add(new Node(childInt));
            }
            else{
                parent = dataAsTree.poll();
            }
            System.out.println ("Current parent " + parent_ +  " with children" + parent_.children);
           }
        return root;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<Integer> dataAsList = Arrays.asList(1, null, 2,3,4, null,5,6,null,7,8,null,9,10);
   //     Node root = buildTree(dataAsList);
        System.out.println ("PreOrder Sorting" + preorder( buildTree(dataAsList)));
    }

    public static List<Integer> preorder(Node root) {
        LinkedList<Integer> res = new LinkedList<>();
        if (root == null) {
            return res;
        }

        preorderhelper(root, res);

        return res;
    }
    private static void preorderhelper(Node root, LinkedList<Integer> res) {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }
         res.add(root.val);
        if (root.children != null) {
            for (Node c : root.children) {
                preorderhelper(c, res);
            }
        }

    }
}
```